# Android - Remove multiple versions of the support library/package?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I think I have multiple versions of the support package. I usually get errors like

> android.support.v4.app.fragmentTransaction cannot be resolved to fragmentTransaction 
>   as an example.

Is there a easy way to fix this? Thanks beforehand

Comment: remove support libraries from project and also from lib- projects u r using in it.
right click on project-->android tools--> Add Support Library.
then paste same library in all library project's lib folder...
Clean & Build  all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the systems fragmentManager just try to use getFragmentManager() instead getSupportFragmentManager().

I think it work well

Answer (score 0):

if you are add Appcompact or any othe library which contains support lib then remove support lib from your App libs directory and clean and build...

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in your **import statement**. 
In One Class you are import android.support.v4.app.fragmentTransaction with support Library  and in another class you used andoird.app.fragmentTransaction Double check it